# Unifying a Servlet Project and a Socket Project in one Project - Class not found Error

Tags: java, sockets, servlets

I have 3 projects. One is a Servlet (made inside a Dynamic Web Project), the other is a socket project (also a Dynamic Web Project) and the last is a real Dynamic Web Project that I want to use to unify the other 2 project and can upload both on my Apache  Tomcat Server (it not my idea, is my boss idea).

I have added the Servlet and Socket project to the Unify Project using "java built path" option on eclipse.

I have run the Unify Project inside Eclipse/Tomcat and when I made a Telnet Command to the Socket, it works!.

But the Servlet Project is not working because Tomcat it can't found the Listener Servlet Class.

I think that the problem is on web.xml of the Unify Project

For me the problem is this line:

```
<servlet-class>
   com.ninatec.fnet3.bussiness_servlet.web.ListenerServlet
</servlet-class>
```

So, how can reference that class from the Servlet Project on the Unify Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to put that class (`com.ninatec.fnet3.bussiness_servlet.web.ListenerServlet`) in the same project as the servlet because that is where's it's used.

If you're unable to do this due to design constraints from your boss then you'd either have to add the other project as a dependency of the servlet project; put the built jar file in the /lib folder of the created war file (or use dependency management such as maven). Or the other solution would be to add it as a Tomcat dependency. To do this when you have a tomcat server instance in eclipse you'd do:

- Servers view
- Double click the Tomcat instance
- Open launch config
- Classpath tab
- Click user entries item
- Add projects
- Select the project with `com.ninatec.fnet3.bussiness_servlet.web.ListenerServlet` in it

But the last solution is probably the worst ideally you'd have the listener class in the servlet project as I doubt it would be used anywhere else, or is it?

Comment: Two questions about that: 1) To add the Servlet Project to the Unify Project as a dependency, I have to add the WAR/JAR file?. It is not enough to use "java built path" option on eclipse and "Deployment Assembly" option??. 2) I have to copy the web.xml content of the Servlet Project to the web.xml of the Unify Project??. Thanks

Comment: Yep the build path within Eclipse is specific to Eclipse not to Tomcat. For Tomcat you'd need to make sure the built servlet has as a dependency the other servlet. This can be done by manually adding the war/jar in or by using a dependency management tool like Maven. A better question would probably be - do you really need to separate the two projects out? If you do need two separate servlets running then I'd recommend you start looking at OSGi.